# Hibernate criteria not populating associations

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using **hibernate criteria api** to get data of txn and txn_products table.
Below is the mapping.

class Txn :

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(value=true)
@Table(name="txn")
public class Txn
{
 @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY , mappedBy = "transaction" , cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<TxnProduct> txnProducts = null;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id" , nullable=false)
    private String id;

......
}
```

class TxnProduct :

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate(true)
@Table(name="txn_product")
public class TxnProduct
{

 @Id
    @Column(name="id" , nullable=false)
    private String id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="txn_id")
    private Txn transaction ;
.....
}
```

business logic :

```
   Session sx = .......... ;
      Criteria Q = sx.createCriteria(Txn.class, "txn");
              Q.createAlias("txn.txnProducts", "txnProducts" , JoinType.INNER_JOIN);

                List<Txn> L = (List<Txn>) Q.list();


                logger.info(L) ;

                for(Txn T : L)
                {
                    logger.info(T);
                    logger.info(T.getTxnProducts());
                }

       sx.close();
```

While executing business logic `List L` returns `Txn` object for each `TxnProduct` in database, but what I expect from hibernate criteria is to return `Txn` object for each row in txn table and set `Set<TxnProduct>` in it.

I tried `Q.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);` but it was not helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Q.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);` should work in most of the cases unless we use pagination on parent entities like `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResult`. There might be some problem with either `JoinType` or `FetchMode`.

Wrapping the `q.list()` with a `Set` will be better alternative irrespective of any fetch modes. Something like 
`Set<Txn> resutls = new HashSet<Txn>(L));` or if you want to return a list again wrap the set with list
`List<Txn> results = new ArrayList<Txn>(new HashSet<Txn>(L));`